# C# motion detection without AForge.net

Tags: c#

Is there a way I can create some basic motion detection code (no need for drawing over a bitmap , some just text that says 'Motion Detected')? Without using the [AForge.net](http://www.aforgenet.com/) framework

Comment: And why can't/won't you use the AForge.net framework, if that does what you want?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen I need to keep the program as small as possible and we only need basic motion detection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [AForge.net](http://www.aforgenet.com), there is no need to draw graphics for motion detection. All you have to do is:

1. Load video
2. Detect motion (`detector.ProcessFrame(FrameFromVideo)`)
3. Check the motion level. If motion level is 0 then there is no
   motion else simply print "Motion Detected"